# Replace characters in a string from a list and create a copy for each

Tags: python, string, replace, sed

I'm not sure if it's even possible to do what I need with sed.

I want to be able to replace a string in a file with another string from a list and create a separate copy for each version.

For example, the original file has:

```
apple dog orange
```

I want to replace `dog` with a list of different words. i.e cat, rabbit, duck.
This would create copies of the original file, each with a different change.

File1.txt (the original file) - `apple dog orange`
File2.txt - `apple cat orange`
File3.txt - `apple rabbit orange`
File4.txt - `apple duck orange`

I've been able to use Sed to find and replace a single file:

```
sed -i '' 's/dog/cat/g' *.html
```

I need a way to replace from a list though, and create a unique copy of each.

I'm on OSX. As I said before, sed might not be the tool to use here, maybe Python? I'm open to any suggestions to do this.

Thanks

Comment: really bad question, the joy of learning how to code is trying and understanding along the way

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with python using regex.

```
import re
import os

filename = '/path/to/filename.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

names = ['cat', 'rabbit', 'duck']
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    new_text = re.sub(r'dog', name, text)
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    with open('{}_{}{}'.format(base, i, ext), 'w') as f:
        f.write(new_text)
```

Comment: I like how you also made sure it was just `dog` and not `dogfish`. Nice work!

Comment: Thanks very much (and kameranis). I actually need it to replace even in the case of `dogfish`. The idea is it is replacing parts of a URL for different regions.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to post so early - 

The idea is to replace part of a URL in a HTML file:

`www.example.com/_en/page` to `www.example.com/_fr/page` or `www.example.com/_de/page` etc.

Comment: @user2382925 Updated to get rid of the word restriction so that it replaces all `dog`'s, even if they're contained within another word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex

```
import re

in_file = 'File1.txt'
out_file = 'File2.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as in_f:
    s = f.read() # Reads whole file. Be careful for large files
    s = re.sub('dog', 'cat', s)
    with open(out_file, 'w') as out_f:
        f.write(s)
```

You can enclose the whole thing in a `for` loop to make as many substitutions as you want

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply using string replace method

```
import string
f = open("file1")
text = f.read()
list_of_words = ['cat','rabbit','duck']
num =2
for word in list_of_words:
    new_text = string.replace(text,"dog",word,1)
    f_new = open("file"+str(num),"w")
    f_new.write(new_text)
    f_new.close()
    num +=1
```

input: 
file1

```
apple dog orange
```

output: file2:

```
apple cat orange
```

output: file3:

```
apple rabbit orange
```

output: file4:

```
apple duck orange
```